# How do I know whether toolbar mode of user's windows is auto-hide or not?

Tags: java, windows, toolbar

I have a Java Swing application. I will do something on my application if user's windows has auto-hide status for its toolbar. I have already looked for it.

Is there any way to get this status? Any suggestion?

Edit: I am talking about windows toolbar not JToolbar

Comment: *"I will do something on my application if user's windows has auto-hide status.."* Why? And more importantly, what? *"Any suggestion ?"* 1) Fix the app. so it doesn't need to know such things. 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) & in future describe the feature you are trying to implement, rather than the process you are trying to use to implement that feature.

Comment: "Why?" Does it matter ? I would like to know that is there any way to know that.

Comment: *"Does it matter ?"* If you want my help (or the help of anyone ales that wants to hear it), then yes. Why, is it a secret?